# GKE Elastic Search only made pods but didn't make any deployment

Tags: elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine

I wanted to run elastic on GKE so I went to the Google Marketplace and did the "Click to deploy Elastic Cluster". Once this was made I did `kubectl get pods` and I got this:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-1-deployer-9xwnp    0/1     Completed   0          5d1h
elasticsearch-1-elasticsearch-0   1/1     Running     0          5d1h
elasticsearch-1-elasticsearch-1   1/1     Running     0          5d1h
```

From there I wanted to get ahold of the dpeloyment they were based on by using `kubectl get deployments` and I get this:

```
No resources found in default namespace.
```

This is really frustrating because I want to be able to have a deployment so that I can start to write a service. I am really new to kubernetes so I am not sure how to move this elasticsearch service from a pod to a deployment.

Has anybody encountered this problem?

---

So as per suggestion I have done `kubectl get deployments -A` and I received the following:

```
kube-system   event-exporter-gke                         1/1     1            1           5d19h
kube-system   fluentd-gke-scaler                         1/1     1            1           5d19h
kube-system   kube-dns                                   2/2     2            2           5d19h
kube-system   kube-dns-autoscaler                        1/1     1            1           5d19h
kube-system   l7-default-backend                         1/1     1            1           5d19h
kube-system   metrics-server-v0.3.6                      1/1     1            1           5d19h
kube-system   stackdriver-metadata-agent-cluster-level   1/1     1            1           5d19h
```

Comment: Have you tried to see in other namespaces? Try the command `kubectl get deployments -A`. Let me know, then I could post a more elaborate answer.

Comment: Hey I just added the result of ```kubectl get deployments -A``` on the main post. Could you take a quick look at it?

Comment: Ok, So I didn't understand your issue. You have deployed ES using 'Click to deploy' and it disapeared afeter a while? Please try to explain in more details what you is trying to achieve, because I'm using this chart on GKE and everything is working fine to me.